# How to specify in visual studio 13 which dll needs to be included

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, include, cmake

I have a project in VS13 and I need it to include few libraries which were compiled using CMake and VS. I have a pair of binaries for a debug and for a release modes. They both have the same names, lets say example.lib and example.dll both for debug and release versions.

Though I can specify separately which example.lib file it needs to include into a project changing a *.lib files in release and debug mode by simply renaming files to something like example_d.lib example_r.lib files, it still does searching for example.dll file in any case. And so every time I change from a release to a debug I need to swap example.dll from one to another and back again.

My question is how to specify catalog which contains certain **both dll and lib** file, or how to specify a certain dll filename to include it into a project?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you rename the `.lib` file, but do not change the `.dll` name inside that `.lib`.

The proper solution is to change the Project Settings when building the DLL, to include `$(Configuration)` in the names.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and edit the vcxproj file manually and add something as below:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <Reference Include="MyLib">
      <HintPath>..\..\Debug\MyLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Reference Include="MyLib">
      <HintPath>..\..\Release\MyLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```